# Making a SVG React Material-UI icon in an NPM module with ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, meteor, svg, material-ui

I created a custom SVG icon in my Meteor/React/Material UI app. The code for the icon is like

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgIcon from 'material-ui/SvgIcon';

let LoadBalancerIcon = (props) => (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>

<circle cx="50" cy="48.75" r="30.43" fill="#f58536"/>
<path fill="#fff" d="M24.42 39.87h11.05v17.76H24.42zM59.73 27.74h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 43.82h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 59.91h9.86v9.86h-9.86z"/>
<path fill="#fff" d="M57.01 50.05l1.64-.81 1.08-.53-1.08-.54-1.46-.72-4.4-2.17v2.17H39.58l15.01-9.61 1.19 1.84 2.49-4.2.73-1.24.73-1.22-1.4.17-1.59.18-4.7.55 1.13 1.74-18.41 11.79-2.03 1.3 2.42 1.54 18.02 11.55-1.13 1.74 4.7.55 1.59.18 1.4.17-.73-1.22-.73-1.24-2.49-4.2-1.19 1.84-15.01-9.61h13.21v2.09l4.22-2.09" />

    </SvgIcon>
);

LoadBalancerIcon.displayName = 'LoadBalancerIcon';
LoadBalancerIcon.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

export default LoadBalancerIcon;
```

That works great so I thought I'd create a NPM module for such icons so others could use it. I created the module with code like

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var  SvgIcon  = require('material-ui/SvgIcon');

class LoadBalancerIcon extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SvgIcon >
                <circle cx="50" cy="48.75" r="30.43" fill="#f58536"/>
                <path fill="#fff" d="M24.42 39.87h11.05v17.76H24.42zM59.73 27.74h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 43.82h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 59.91h9.86v9.86h-9.86z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" d="M57.01 50.05l1.64-.81 1.08-.53-1.08-.54-1.46-.72-4.4-2.17v2.17H39.58l15.01-9.61 1.19 1.84 2.49-4.2.73-1.24.73-1.22-1.4.17-1.59.18-4.7.55 1.13 1.74-18.41 11.79-2.03 1.3 2.42 1.54 18.02 11.55-1.13 1.74 4.7.55 1.59.18 1.4.17-.73-1.22-.73-1.24-2.49-4.2-1.19 1.84-15.01-9.61h13.21v2.09l4.22-2.09" />
            </SvgIcon>
        );
    }
}

LoadBalancerIcon.displayName = 'LoadBalancerIcon';
LoadBalancerIcon.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

module.exports = LoadBalancerIcon;
```

but when I use that in the application I get this error

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

I'm using Babel to transpile the file and I can see the transpiled file is like:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var SvgIcon = require('material-ui/SvgIcon');

class LoadBalancerIcon extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            SvgIcon,
            null,
            React.createElement('circle', { cx: '50', cy: '48.75', r: '30.43', fill: '#f58536' }),
            React.createElement('path', { fill: '#fff', d: 'M24.42 39.87h11.05v17.76H24.42zM59.73 27.74h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 43.82h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 59.91h9.86v9.86h-9.86z' }),
            React.createElement('path', { fill: '#fff', d: 'M57.01 50.05l1.64-.81 1.08-.53-1.08-.54-1.46-.72-4.4-2.17v2.17H39.58l15.01-9.61 1.19 1.84 2.49-4.2.73-1.24.73-1.22-1.4.17-1.59.18-4.7.55 1.13 1.74-18.41 11.79-2.03 1.3 2.42 1.54 18.02 11.55-1.13 1.74 4.7.55 1.59.18 1.4.17-.73-1.22-.73-1.24-2.49-4.2-1.19 1.84-15.01-9.61h13.21v2.09l4.22-2.09' })
        );
    }
}

LoadBalancerIcon.displayName = 'LoadBalancerIcon';
LoadBalancerIcon.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

module.exports = LoadBalancerIcon;
```

If I write the file not in ES6 like:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var mui = require('material-ui');
var SvgIcon = mui.SvgIcon;

var LoadBalancerIcon = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'LoadBalancerIcon',

    render: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
            SvgIcon,
            this.props,
            [
                React.createElement('circle', { cx: '50', cy: '48.75', r: '30.43', fill: '#f58536' }),
                React.createElement('path', { d: 'M24.42 39.87h11.05v17.76H24.42zM59.73 27.74h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 43.82h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 59.91h9.86v9.86h-9.86z', fill: '#fff' }),
                React.createElement('path', { d: 'M57.01 50.05l1.64-.81 1.08-.53-1.08-.54-1.46-.72-4.4-2.17v2.17H39.58l15.01-9.61 1.19 1.84 2.49-4.2.73-1.24.73-1.22-1.4.17-1.59.18-4.7.55 1.13 1.74-18.41 11.79-2.03 1.3 2.42 1.54 18.02 11.55-1.13 1.74 4.7.55 1.59.18 1.4.17-.73-1.22-.73-1.24-2.49-4.2-1.19 1.84-15.01-9.61h13.21v2.09l4.22-2.09', fill: '#fff' })
            ]
        );
    }

});

module.exports = LoadBalanceIcon;
```

It works fine but I'd rather write it in ES6. What could be the issue?

Comment: seems not config babel right. how the .babelrc looks like

Comment: Can't seem to find an edit link to include .babelrc it looks like {
 "presets": ["es2016", "react"],
 "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}

Comment: I don't know much about react, but I notice that in your first example you are doing `<SvgIcon {...props}>` but then in your npm module it is `<SvgIcon >`.  This seems to result in a `null` for your 2nd argument in `React.createElement` in your transpiled code (vs. `this.props` in your non-ES6 version).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In the (non-ES6) code that works, I had

```
var SvgIcon = mui.SvgIcon;
```

versus

```
var  SvgIcon  = require('material-ui/SvgIcon');
```

Changing that fixed the problem. Changing require to import and the complete example looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import mui, {SvgIcon} from 'material-ui';

export default class LoadBalancerIcon extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SvgIcon {...this.props} >
                <circle cx="50" cy="48.75" r="30.43" fill="#f58536"/>
                <path fill="#fff" d="M24.42 39.87h11.05v17.76H24.42zM59.73 27.74h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 43.82h9.86v9.86h-9.86zM59.73 59.91h9.86v9.86h-9.86z"/>
                <path fill="#fff" d="M57.01 50.05l1.64-.81 1.08-.53-1.08-.54-1.46-.72-4.4-2.17v2.17H39.58l15.01-9.61 1.19 1.84 2.49-4.2.73-1.24.73-1.22-1.4.17-1.59.18-4.7.55 1.13 1.74-18.41 11.79-2.03 1.3 2.42 1.54 18.02 11.55-1.13 1.74 4.7.55 1.59.18 1.4.17-.73-1.22-.73-1.24-2.49-4.2-1.19 1.84-15.01-9.61h13.21v2.09l4.22-2.09" />
            </SvgIcon>
        );
    }
}

LoadBalancerIcon.displayName = 'LoadBalancerIcon';
LoadBalancerIcon.muiName = 'LoadBalancerIcon';
```